# Conversation handler not advancing to next state on Heroku correctly

Tags: python, django, heroku, python-telegram-bot

I've developed a webhook-type Telegram bot that is integrated into a Django application using the python-telegram-bot(v13.15) library. Locally, the conversation handler works correctly, but after deploying the application to Heroku, it sometimes fails to advance to the next state in the conversation. Instead, it treats incoming messages as if they are part of the echo handler, and only advances to the next state after the user sends the message again. I've checked that everything is set up correctly on Heroku and there are no delays between messages, so I'm not sure what could be causing the problem.

[Example of conversation handler using Heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZgXM.png)

[Example of conversation handler locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cipyT.png)

Here's the relevant code:

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseBadRequest
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

from telegram_bot.buttons import *
from telegram_bot.handlers.cart_handler import *
from telegram_bot.handlers.checkout_handler import *
from telegram_bot.handlers.delivery_handler import *
from telegram_bot.handlers.order_handler import *
from telegram_bot.handlers.payment_handler import *
from telegram_bot.handlers.product_handler import *
from telegram_bot.utils import *


@debug_requests
def start_handler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    context.bot.send_message(
        chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
        text="Hello! I'm a bot. What can I do for you?",
        reply_markup=get_base_reply_keyboard()
    )


@debug_requests
def echo_handler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    text = update.message.text

    if text == BUTTON1_CATEGORIES:
        categories_handler(update, context)
    elif text == BUTTON2_CART:
        get_cart_handler(update, context)
    elif text == BUTTON3_HELP:
        return do_help(update, context)
    elif text == BUTTON4_ORDERS:
        return user_orders_list_handler(update, context)
    else:
        reply_text = 'Press any button below'
        update.message.reply_text(
            text=reply_text,
            reply_markup=get_base_reply_keyboard(),
        )


webhook_url = settings.TELEGRAM_WEBHOOK_URL
bot_token = settings.TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN
bot = Bot(token=bot_token)
updater = Updater(token=bot_token)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
    entry_points=[
        CallbackQueryHandler(start_order_handler, pattern='checkout_start'),
    ],
    states={
        C_FIRST_NAME: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, customer_first_name_handler)],
        C_LAST_NAME: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, customer_last_name_handler)],
        C_EMAIL: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, customer_email_handler)],
        PHONE: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, customer_phone_handler)],
        RECIPIENT: [CallbackQueryHandler(recipient_handler)],
        R_FIRST_NAME: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, recipient_first_name_handler)],
        R_LAST_NAME: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, recipient_last_name_handler)],
        R_EMAIL: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, recipient_email_handler)],
        COUPON: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, coupon_handler)],
        REGION: [CallbackQueryHandler(region_handler)],
        CITY: [CallbackQueryHandler(city_handler)],
        ADDRESS: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, address_handler)],
        DELIVERY: [CallbackQueryHandler(delivery_handler)],
        CONFIRM: [CallbackQueryHandler(confirm_info_handler)],
        PAYMENT: [CallbackQueryHandler(payment_handler)],
        PAYMENT_CHECK: [CallbackQueryHandler(payment_check_handler)]
    },
    fallbacks=[
        CommandHandler('cancel', cancel_handler),
    ],
    conversation_timeout=0,
)

dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start_handler))
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('categories', categories_handler))
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('cart', get_cart_handler))
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('orders', user_orders_list_handler))
dispatcher.add_handler(conv_handler)
dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button_callback_handler))
dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.all, echo_handler))

bot.setWebhook(webhook_url)

@csrf_exempt
@debug_requests
def telegram_webhook(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        json_string = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        update = Update.de_json(json.loads(json_string), updater.bot)
        dispatcher.process_update(update)
        return HttpResponse(status=200)
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest('Invalid request method')
```

What could be causing the conversation handler to fail to advance to the next state on Heroku? Are there any limitations or restrictions on the Telegram API that I should be aware of? I'm using the same version of the python-telegram-bot library locally and on Heroku, and I've checked the Heroku logs for any errors, but haven't found anything that seems to be causing the problem. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

I've tried checking the version of the python-telegram-bot library that I'm using locally and on Heroku to make sure they are the same. I also tried to debug, but I did not find anything that could cause this problem.

### A small update on this topic.

I decided to try another service to host the django application and deployed it to Railway. Oddly enough, this hosting service does not have the same problem in conversation as Heroku. Therefore it is not very clear what the problem is with Heroku, but if anyone has faced a similar problem, I will be glad to hear some tips to solve it.

Comment: Please note that the `python-telegram-bot` dev team no longer provides support for version 13.x or older. I encourage you to upgrade to the latest version: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-20.0

Comment: Yes, I know, but I haven't found an example of how you can implement a telegram bot on the new version of the library in a Django application. If you can tell me where to read or find some examples, I will be very grateful.